# Shadow of the hidden window when minimize the parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with wpf c#, I set the visibility of the child window to hidden on closing. But when I minimized the parent window, or clicked on the parent window from taskbar, there comes a shadow like window of the hidden child window.How can I avoid this.

Comment: Please show us how you have hidden the child window.

Comment: try
                        {
                          typeof(Window).GetField("_isClosing", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(this, false);
                          e.Cancel = true;
                          this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                          this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                         UIMediator.UIMediatorInstance.ActivatePatientviewer = true;
                                     
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            
                        }

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Visibility.Collapsed instead of Visibility.Hidden